# VBS to save with cell reference and timestamp

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I have a vb script which executes an excel macro and saves the file appending the name with a specific cell value and a timestamp as well. But it's not working and i'm totally lost as to the reason.

If i take out the cell reference and timestamp pieces out, it executes and saves correctly. Any help or material i can review would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
Option Explicit

On Error Resume Next

ExcelMacroExample

Sub ExcelMacroExample() 

Dim objApp  
Dim objExcel  
Dim objWorkbook
Dim objSheet

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\midi\Desktop\EN\SCORES.xlsm")
Set objSheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets("Cover Tab") 
Set SiteIdentifier = objSheet.Cells("B4").Value  

objExcel.Run "RefreshConns"
WScript.Sleep 30000 

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\midi\Desktop\EN\SCORES_" & SiteIdentifier & "_"& Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd_hhnnss") & ".xlsm", 52

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close

objExcel.Quit   


End Sub
```

Comment: Should this `yyyymmdd_hhnnss` be this `yyyymmdd_hhmmss`? Try defining a string that will contain the full filename and debug print the filename.

Comment: I switched it but still no luck.. it's the weirdest thing, the script runs and excel does what it has to (I monitor in task manager) but it doesn't seem to complete the save and close the application. I'll do that now, thanks @OldUgly

Comment: What does SiteIdentifier evaluate to? Will it contribute to an invalid file name?

Comment: [See this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw949162(v=vs.90).aspx) - is the length of full filename (including path) longer than 218 characters?

Comment: Comment out the `On Error Resume Next` line for the time being and see if you are getting any error messages.

Comment: Remove the `Set` before 'SiteIdentifier' so it reads `SiteIdentifier = objSheet.Cells("B4").Value`

Comment: @OldUgly SiteIdentifier is a 4 character string. The path length is well under 218 characters (98).

Comment: @SearchAndResQ thank you! I got "Variable is undefined: Format" which lead me to believe that Format isn't a vbs function. I fixed the date/time stamp. But the reference to my cell isn't working

Comment: @JordanBiddlecombe I removed the Set but that's just giving me an "Invalid procedure" error

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your advices, helped me see what my errors were. Posting the answer for closure.

```
Option Explicit

ExcelMacroExample

Sub ExcelMacroExample() 

  Dim objApp  
  Dim objExcel  
  Dim objWorkbook
  Dim objSheet
  Dim SiteIdentifier

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\midi\Desktop\EN\SCORES.xlsm")
Set objSheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets("Cover Tab") 

SiteIdentifier = objSheet.Cells(4, 2).Value

 objExcel.Run "RefreshConns"
    WScript.Sleep 60000 

 objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\midi\Desktop\EN\SCORES_" & SiteIdentifier & "_" & Year(Now()) & Month(Now()) & Day(Now()) & "_" & Hour(Now()) & Minute(Now()) & Second(Now())&".xlsm", 52

 objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close

 objExcel.Quit   


End Sub
```

Comment: If you're looking for a why, its because the `Set` function is used for objects/ranges, not strings. When setting string values you just use an `=`; alternatively you could have done `Set SiteIdentifier = objSheet.Cells(4, 2)` and then used `SiteIdentifier.Value` in your `SaveAs` statement.